# Is it possible to run code after pop back stack

Tags: android, kotlin

```
requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner) {
    findNavController().popBackStack()
    //runs after popping off the back stack
    (activity as MainActivity).toolbar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
```

Is it possible to run code after popBackStack() given the fragment is already gone? If I put breakpoints, I found out that (activity as MainActivity).toolbar.visibility = View.VISIBLE runs before the fragment's onPause() why it is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `popBackStack` works asynchronously:

> Pop all back stack states up to the one with the given identifier. This function is asynchronous -- it enqueues the request to pop, but the action will not be performed until the application returns to its event loop.
>   (see [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager#popBackStack()))

There's an alternative [popBackStackImmediate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager#popBackStackImmediate()).